# Allow a logged in user to insert into database WPF

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I would like a logged in user to store data in the database which will only be seen by them. There are no user roles just one type of user with the ability to perform CRUD functionalities.

```
    public bool Create(SemesterDetails details)
    {
     
       SqlConnection  db = new SqlConnection(AppConnect.Connection);

        try
        {
            string  insModule = "INSERT INTO [Module](moduleCode,moduleName,modCredits,modHrsPerWeek)" +

          "VALUES('" + details.ModuleCode + "', +'" + details.ModuleName + "', '" + details.ModuleCredits + "', '" +details.ModuleStudyHrs+ "')";
            if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                db.Open();

                command = new SqlCommand(insModule,db);
                int i = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (i>0)
                {
                   return true;
                }
                db.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);            
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The above code inserts values to the database.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Using MSSQL ADO.net

Comment: Learn to parameterize your queries - write more secure code! Learn about `USING` - write  better c# code.

Comment: You ***need*** to fix that huge security hole in your code. Stop injecting values into your statements. It's not the 90's anymore; learn from other people's stupid mistakes.

Comment: If you want rows that can only be seen by the user, you need to look into Row Level Security (RLS).

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your version (please always specify!), [Row-Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security) is probably the feature you are looking for, but note there is a [measurable performance impact](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4778/performance-impact-of-sql-server-2016-rowlevel-security/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) as well as [some other caveats](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4005/sql-server-2016-row-level-security-limitations-performance-and-troubleshooting/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

A simplistic way to do this *for future rows* could be to add a new column with a default:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- let's add a column to capture the creator
-- (for a brief moment, this will be you):
ALTER TABLE dbo.Module 
  ADD OwningPerson nvarchar(128) NOT NULL
  DEFAULT SUSER_SNAME();
GO

-- now let's make existing rows visible to all
-- (but you can go back and update them manually):
UPDATE dbo.Module SET OwningPerson = N'legacy';

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Now, if you insert a new row, this column will have the value of the contextual user.

Then, to make sure users can only see their own rows, you can deny select on the table, and force them to read through this view (*this* is where a database-level role might come in handy):

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.OnlyMyModules
AS
  SELECT <cols> 
    FROM dbo.Module 
    WHERE OwningPerson IN (N'legacy', SUSER_SNAME());
```

(Or maybe you want to prevent users from seeing the legacy modules until you can go back and properly assign them to users.)

You should also create (and protect) a stored procedure so that you/admins can retrieve the rows for any user:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CheckUserModules
  @username nvarchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT <cols> 
    FROM dbo.Module 
    WHERE OwningPerson = @username;
END
```

Comment: Hi @Aaron Bertrand, this works but it gives my PC name as owningPerson

Comment: @Jacob `SUSER_SNAME()` returns your PC name? That is interesting, exactly how are you connecting to SQL Server? Try with an explicit SQL auth user or your Windows account, or however your users and/or the app will connect. There are several other security identifier functions you can try, too, like `ORIGINAL_LOGIN`, `CURRENT_USER`, `USER_NAME`, `SESSION_USER`, etc.

Comment: ^ try `SELECT SUSER_SNAME(), ORIGINAL_LOGIN(), CURRENT_USER, USER_NAME(), SESSION_USER;` both as you *and* in the context of whatever your app does so you can decide which security function is going to work.

Comment: I meant it gives me the SQL username not the user name entered by the user

Comment: Ok, well if the user authenticates as a generic SQL auth user and not through Windows Authentication, SQL Server doesn't know who they are. So perhaps you could consider `HOST_NAME()` which would identify the machine at least, or if it's web-based or jumpbox/terminal client based, you could append their username to the application name in the connection string and then use a portion of `PROGRAM_NAME()`.

Comment: @Jacob do you mean the user supplies their username? If the username is available to you in the C# code then you could simply add the new column to the insert statement (but please parameterize that thing, then add a 5th parameter for the new column).

Comment: ...but that doesn't seem like a very good plan if you're also relying on whatever the user supplied to be their username in order to look up the modules that belong to them...

Comment: Sorry to reply after such a long time but I stored username in file so that i can access it everywhere in the project.